# Number of cores used doing parallel programming in R

Tags: r, parallel-processing, cpu-cores

I use the following code in order to run my code in different cores at the same time.

I use 7 workers and as you can see I have to run my code for 90 (number of rows of grid_models) different simulation designs.

While 94% of the 90 designs have been completed, I have more than one remaining. However, I see that only one core is used, and so the remaining six cores are not used. This happens when I have some remaining desings (~6% of 90). For the 94% of the the 90 designs all the cores are used. Do you know why? How can I fix this?

In other words, for the last remaining of the 90 designs, even if more than one designs remain, only one core used.

Here is the code:

```
#   Libraries                                                              

packages <- c(
  "doFuture",
  "parallel",
  "doParallel",
  "foreach",
  "future",
  "progressr"
)

# Install packages not yet installed
installed_packages <- packages %in% rownames(installed.packages())
if (any(installed_packages == FALSE)) {
  install.packages(packages[!installed_packages])
}

# Packages loading
invisible(lapply(packages, library, character.only = TRUE))


# Models Specification

grid_models <- expand.grid(n_obs = c(1:5), cor_mat = c(1:3), beta = c(1:2), active_var = c(1:3))

vasilis <- list()

# Register the parallel backend
plan(multisession, workers = 7)

# Run the loop in parallel
opts <- list(progress = progress,
             packages = c("glmnet"),
             seed = TRUE)
options(future.globals.maxSize= 891289600)


# Parallel Code
with_progress({
  Progress <- progressor(along = 1:nrow(grid_models))
system.time( vasilis <- foreach(J = 1:nrow(grid_models),.options.future = opts) %dofuture% {
      
# some code used here that ends creating a matrix named Results

Results

Progress()

})
  })
```

Comment: One possible scenario is that the jobs get assigned to cores in packs divisible by your workers. So you're just seeing the last pack being processed on a single core.

Comment: @AndreWildberg actually I think that this is not true, becuase when a job is done, then another one starts. So, I think that the jobs do not get assigned to cores in packs.

Comment: Viewing it from a different angle, to always see all cores on 100% load at the end, all remaining jobs have to finish at the same time, which is very unlikely. Some scheduling definitely takes place, so as jobs finish, some are still running, and the last one(s) will run on just one core.